# как убрать убрать пространство при уменьшении

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Когда ээмулирую на айфон к примеру или айпад, появляеться пространство! картинка как бы сползает вниз черезчур(

```css
.header-text {
   font-family: Neuron;
color: #000000;
font-size: 48px; /* Приближение из-за подстановки шрифтов */
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 24px; /* Приближение из-за подстановки шрифтов */
text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.head {
   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(img/head.jpg)no-repeat 50% / contain ;
 
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="header-text">Hello, world!</div>
</div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class= "col-md-12">
         <div class="head"> </div>
          <div class="container">
         
       </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

У вас для `.head` стоит высота во весь экран, вот блок и тянется во весь экран, добавьте медиа запросы в зависимости от тех размеров, что вам нужны, например:

```css
.header-text {
   font-family: Neuron;
color: #000000;
font-size: 48px; /* Приближение из-за подстановки шрифтов */
font-weight: 300;
line-height: 24px; /* Приближение из-за подстановки шрифтов */
text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.head {
   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(img/head.jpg)no-repeat 50% / contain ;
 
}

/*media*/
@media (max-width:767px){
  .head {
    height: 70vh;
  }
}
@media (max-width:575px){
  .head {
    height: 30vh;
  }
}
/*media*/
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="header-text">Hello, world!</div>
</div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class= "col-md-12">
         <div class="head"> </div>
          <div class="container">
         
       </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```